# App to build a Virtual Box VDI virtual machine for Ubuntu

Tags: virtual-machine

I make quite a few VirtualBox VMs; for instance, one for development, one for gaming, etc and then to put a fair bit of research time into getting the VM just right.

Is there an app which uses a Wizard, something like the [SUSE Studio](https://susestudio.com/), where I would select the VM parameters (disk size, RAM usage, shared folders, etc) plus the apps which I would  like to have installed, and generates a virtual machine for me?